# awesome-wm: Possible to to map Alt+Shift?

Tags: lua, debian, awesome-wm

Using Debian (jessie) and the "awesome" window manager (3.4.15), I can't figure out how to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to a command. I would like to switch my keyboard layout like on a windows box. 
This is what I do to test the mapping:

```
awful.key({ "Alt",},"Shift", function ()awful.util.spawn("xfce4-terminal") end),
```

Of course the aforementioned line us within a

```
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join( ...
```

just like the other (working) hotkeys. Has anyone managed to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as a shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me (figured this out by experimenting + running `xev` and looking at its output a bit):

```
awful.key({ "Mod1" }, "Shift_L", function () print("key 1") end),
awful.key({ "Shift" }, "Alt_L", function () print("key 2") end),
```

The first one is for when you press Alt first while the second one is for when Shift is pressed first (yup, this makes a difference; pressing Shift while "a" is pressed also does something else than the opposite order).

Answer (score 4):

In Awesome WM, Whilst control key is "Control", Alt is "Mod1".

So, you would have this kind of syntax:

```
awful.key({ "Mod1", "Control"}, "KEY(for example j)" , function desired...),
```